# Mapping textid's to text

Tags: java, spring

I have application written in spring, it communicate with another application, I received objects and now I have to map text id's to text in specific (given in object) language.

File with text id's and text looks like:

message.id=message

There is one file per language.

I'm looking for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring provides some built-in support for internationalization in the form of `MessageSource`s. See [3.13.1 Internationalization using MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource).

Answer (score 0):

That's a job for the Java ResouceBundle class.

Basic usage:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("path.on.the.classpath", requiredLocale);
String text = bundle.getString(textId);
```

You should handle MissingResourceExceptions etc. and maybe you even want to cache the bundles like some libraries/webframeworks do.